# I don't know how to get gazebo updated information

Tags: gazebo, ros2, control

[image]

`/cmd_vel` Sends the speed value as a message to `drff_drive`.

`/diff_drive` sends the following two:

1. `/odom` (pose and vel of odom frame)
2. `/tf` (transform information every real-time)

`/joint_state` simply passed robot information.

Does `/diff_drive` transmit the converted information to Gazebo through parameters?

Thank you very much

Comment: Or can I assume that /odom and /tf are continuously updated and are only displayed in Gazebo?

Comment: Please don't comment to your question but edit the original one.
Furthermore, please add information about your ROS distro, gazebo version, and the necessary parts of the gazebo configuration file (which plugins do you use etc)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me what you want to get from Gazebo. Are you talking about model states? Or what exactly? There are a few services published by Gazebo that you could use such as `/gazebo/get_model_state` or topics that tell you data from the simulation. If this wasn't your question, I encourage you to explain a bit more about your task.

Edit1: If the controller used is a Gazebo Plugin based such as `diff_drive_controller` from ROS, it would be related to Gazebo. If you instead used a controller from ros_control as an example, that's the one calculating the odometry based in equations and variables such as wheels velocities inputted. I'm not experienced in `ros_control` so if this is your case, you can see more information here: https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

First, I have confirmed that there is a problem with my current code (controller not running), so I think the above graph may not be right.

Ultimately, what I wanted fortunately had nothing to do with the above. It was about how it is updated when the robot's state changes due to `/cmd_vel`. Does this have nothing to do with gazebo?
As written in the comment above, we were able to confirm topics that were continuously updated.

Comment: Please see my edited answer